# Editing post reputation requirement is too high?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please reduce the threshold for editing other people’s posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/please-reduce-the-threshold-for-editing-other-peoples-posts)

I have seen quite a few posts where I wanted to edit the original question or at least supplement the question with some clarification to help the poster. At the moment, people sometimes make comments to steer the original poster, and higher rep people tend to simply close the posting. The current experience is kinda sink or swim, just wondering if maybe adding a feature to help with this or lowering rep to be able to edit post would possibly be a good idea?

Comment: i felt the same way when i started out on the trilogy.  (still feel that way when i wander onto SF or SO.)  the abilities are doled out at intervals to give new users time to get familiar with how the sites work.  for example, if you'd done some searching before posting this, you might've [discovered an earlier post asking for the same thing.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/please-reduce-the-threshold-for-editing-other-peoples-posts)

Comment: i see, maybe add a line in the faq that asks people to look for the question before they post because I did go through the suggestions that appeared when i was putting the answer together and did not see this earlier post.

Comment: checking if what you ask was posted already on the site you go to ask goes without saying, in my opinion. But even if you posted a duplicate because you couldn't find the previous question, it's not a big deal in itself, your question got closed as duplicate by someone else, nothing more than that, no offense to take.

Comment: it's already in the faq: *"Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask."*