# What's going on with the downvotes on Rich B's questions?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I just noticed three questions that Rich B made which have negative votes:

> *[Why is my simple C program displaying garbage to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260235/why-is-my-simple-c-program-displaying-garbage-to-stdout)* (fixed)
>
> *[Is there a good library for dealing with the Modbus protocol in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837/modbus-net)* (fixed)
>
> *[How can I make the format document shortcut work for C source files in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269003/how-can-i-make-the-format-document-shortcut-work-for-c-source-files-in-vs2008)*

In all three cases the questions do not warrant a negative score.

Is this an example of rage votes because people do not like him?

Comment: You do realize that Rich B is *the* most prolific down voter on SO, right?  Not that it warrants retaliatory down votes, but it certainly is funny to see this Question.

Comment: @Stu: Yes, but there's always a reason behind his votes that are due to content. Rarely are they personal (I have to say rarely since I'm not in his head, thankfully). These are three legitimate questions very wrongly in the negatives.

Comment: You title is somewhat misleading on first glance: I thought this was about BS questions (that also happened to be rich). Luckily I'm smart, so it didn't take me long to figure it out.

Comment: @Eric: I'm not debating it either way, just pointing out that little factoid.  Relax.

Comment: The MSO community seems to have largely rectified matters...

Comment: It is just serial down voting. I am used to it. There are a lot of small and petty people on SO.com, and I have become their target. That is ok with me. I still believe I do good work.

Comment: BTW, I had already made mention of this in a question on MSO and it seems like I drew out many of the people who seem to support and possibly take part in this behavior. Lets hope their time within our community is short. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/how-often-do-people-get-serial-down-voted

Comment: maybe it's the thedailywtf people attacking masterplansoftware?

Comment: First question is not fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not rightly sure. Rich, more than most, tends to have a lot of animosity built up. These questions are simplistic in nature, and people are railing on him for it, which is rather wrong, IMO. While I've certainly sparred a bit with him, I don't think he deserves a down voting to oblivion on very old questions (the newest is from 11/6/08). I've given an upvote to them all.

So taking a look at [the Sandbox](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/), it turns out that the first vote for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269003) did not come until 2/10/09--three months after posting. It was a downvote, by the way. In fact, two downvotes were registered at the <strike>*exact same timestamp* (1234252800)</strike> (it appears this is rounded to the nearest 100th, which means they were registered within 100 seconds of each other). The last vote was registered on 6/30/09 (in the data dump--obviously stopping at June). There were five consecutive down votes from 5/11/09 to 6/11/09.

You can get the votes with the following query:

```
select 
    case votetypeid 
        when 2 then 'Up' 
        when 3 then 'Down' 
        else 'N/A' 
    end as votetype, 
    creationdate 
from 
    votes 
where 
    postid = 269003 
order by 2
```

Note: `dateformat(creationdate, '%m/%d/%y')` fails out, so you can use this handy-dandy [UNIX Epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

So, it doesn't look like it was one concerted effort or fraud. Just a few retaliatory votes that resulted in a bit of group thought. Sad, but a fact of life. All three questions exhibit the same behavior--multiple votes over time, not one specific fraud or event.

Answer (score 2):

Did you notice you noticed questions from 10, 9 and 8 months back?

Some kind of [tag-edit war went on in the C shortcut question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/269003/list) while another one had a user cut him off at the end.

In two of those questions, there is [one user that appears on both](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51816/joan-venge) with the RTFM comments.

Looks retaliatory.