# Punish serial downvoting

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, serial-voting

There is a daily/nightly script to correct 'chain hate downvote pattern'. I propose to punish the 'hater' by taking the amount of reputation points from his/her account that he/she removed from the victim.

[Feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102884/do-you-need-feedback). The victim should be notified (inbox) that the script has been run, and the "hater" should be notified as well. The victim should not be informed as to the identity of the "hater" of course.

Maybe a moderator should be notified as well to take additional action against the "hater", or not? **Edit** Maybe a [day in the penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)?

P.S. I've had a bout of downvotes, but nothing serious.

P.P.S I've not suffered this problem myself.

P.P.P.S As 'gnat' noticed, this is about **feedback**.

**Edit** Funny that proposals against downvoting get seriously downvoted.

Comment: Being a victim of vote-crime entitles you to have your rightful rep restored, but not compensation. What if your answers were not worthy of an upvote?

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Edited the proposal.

Comment: I would love this to work for serial upvoting too. On a serious note, there are already script which run daily that detect suspicious voting pattern.

Comment: Why? (15 chars)

Comment: @Myself (To Myself), that's just what I've said in the first sentence.

Comment: @GUI - you say what you want to do but not what the reasoning is.  The system catches this and reverses it, so what do you want to punish exactly?  The temporary inconvenience of having slightly lower rep for a short span of time?

Comment: @JNK not at all, I think it's obvious: Serial downvoting/upvoting is 'bad' behavior that should be punished.

Comment: Anyway, it is a real issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/how-often-do-people-get-serial-down-voted

Comment: Does the voter fraud script return the -1 rep taken from the abuser for each of their downvotes? If it doesn't, I'd say justice is already served.

Comment: @Robert I haven't seen that anywhere, so I don't know. But -1 is not really a deterrent. SE is an economy of points, abuse of the system should be punished accordingly.

Comment: +1 _"Feedback. The victim should be notified (inbox) that the script has been run, and the "hater" should be notified as well."_

Comment: how i can see some user who has downvote me because i thing some one doing unneccessory downvoting

Comment: @VipanKumar, you can't. Only moderators (etc.) can see that. But if you are 'victim' you can ask team@SE to look into it. Anyway, receiving some downvotes shouldn't be considered as a personal attack.

Answer (score 5):

Why bother?

The serial down-voter isn't interested in the loss of their own reputation.

When the votes are removed a reputation recalculation is performed on both parties. The change in reputation caused by this is more than likely going to mask any reduction given as "punishment".

Comment: Come on, downvoting costs 1 reputation and is also sometimes free. No reasonable person would be worried about the rep loss caused by downvoting.

Comment: @Kop - you'd be surprised. Witness the increase in down-voting questions since it became free.

Comment: this is just because people are stupid and in their mind the difference between a $0.00 pen and a $0.01 pen is much bigger than the difference between a $0.01 pen and a $0.02. But some people are not stupid, so a non-stupid serial downvoter can be a serial downvoter while still being interested in their rep =p

Comment: @Kop - that is probably true. I've removed what, in retrospect, was an unnecessary statement.

Comment: Or are they? We don't know that unless the cost of serial downvoting goes up. A 10€ pen may be more of a deterrent.

Comment: @GUIJunkie then everybody just switches to pencils (EE :P).

Comment: @Andreas, actually, our brains work with logarithmic (not linear) scales; not with differences, but reasons. And that means we automatically see that a 1 cent pen is half the cost of a 2 cent pen, but infinitely more expensive than a free pen.