# How can I check who downvoted my posts?

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial downvotes in quick succession on all my posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts)

Someone just downvoted every single answer I gave on Stack Overflow in 10mins.

```
-2  6 mins ago  downvote    PHP E-mail Form Sender Name Instead Of E-mail?
-2  6 mins ago  downvote    how to get the second class in jquery?
-2  6 mins ago  downvote    Facebook Like button flips backs to 'unliked' state after clicking
-2  6 mins ago  downvote    jquery remove hidden form value after form submit
-2  6 mins ago  downvote    Hover Link Colour, CSS
-2  6 mins ago  downvote    Best jQuery Mobile Page Setup
-2  6 mins ago  downvote    The one book for html, css, javascript
-2  32 mins ago     downvote    Beginning with PHP?
-2  34 mins ago     downvote    HTML/CSS Margin issue
-2  34 mins ago     downvote    Generating PHPass for Wordpress Passwords
-2  34 mins ago     downvote    Where to find code Snippets for PHP?
-2  34 mins ago     downvote    Twitter Stream API with PHP/Javascript Implimentation
-2  35 mins ago     downvote    Front end developer Training
-2  35 mins ago     downvote    @font-face Blacklisted font
```

Is there some way to report this activity? Link to profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/387387/tarun?tab=reputation

Comment: thanks Cody Gray, yes its a duplicate. I tried to search for it but didn't find, didn't knw there is a term for it, but spotted the serial-downvote keyword when adding tag.

Comment: FYI, I was able to identify the user and this has been dealt with.

Comment: Thanks Tim :) I hope i get the rep. points back.

total of 32 downvotes.

Answer (score 11):

Votes are anonymous, but voting behaviour like this should be automatically detected and reverted within a day. If they are not, you can email `team@stackoverflow.com` and they can look into it for you.

Comment: @Tarun Someone just did this to all of my posts as well. Maybe there's a bot, or someone in a particularly bad mood...

Comment: just got 13 more downvotes =(

Comment: Poor folks youse! I've upvoted your comments to comfort you:)

Comment: @JeremyBanks: and is voter punished for these votes?

Comment: @genesis [No, they're not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98055/punish-serial-downvoting), although I would expect the team to do something in particularly abusive cases.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check who downvoted my posts?

[image]

I think you already have some clue. According to voting stats, it looks say so.

Comment: yeah, i realized it that it would be this guy. He seems very very angry that I downvoted him.

Comment: Where's the link?!? How are all of the Meta users going to enact their revenge by downvoting *his* answers?