# Overzealous fan makes my rep explode then reversal ensues. Is the fan punished for such behavior?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, serial-voting

I was surprised last morning to wake up to 666 rep, a 150 more than I had the night before. I looked at my rep ledger and saw that almost all of my answers were upvoted in a span of about 10 minutes. I thought to myself, how nice... I have a fan :)

Later during the day I found out all about the serial upvoting policy, since I have experienced it first hand - which, ***IMO is a very sensible policy***. The only problem I see with it is, that it has now left a sort of a blemish on my rep ledger (-150 rep all at once), that I can't seem to remove, which is fine in the end, I guess, but makes me a little sad, especially considering that this act was not solicited from my side and even more so, because it seems like someone wanted me to have 666 for my rep, seeing how they stopped the serial upvote when they reached that number.

In conclusion, I'd like to ask whether the perpetrators of serial upvoting receive some kind of sanction for their actions or do they walk free?

Comment: There was a recent post commenting about how the reversal of the upvotes does, in fact, look 'bad' for the recipient, even though the recipient did not (necessarily) do anything deserving of it. Someone would have to be aware of how the serial reversal system works to understand that it's not necessarily a blemish on the person at the receiving end.

Comment: My thoughts exactly!

Comment: *Sneaks of to __carefully__ upvote some questions of the OP*. With our help you'll be back to 666 in no time! :-P

Comment: Here's that Q: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139080/please-hide-serial-upvoting-reversed-entries-in-the-public-reputation-history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the serial voters don't get punished, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98294/184981). In fact, if they've lost rep by serial downvoting on answers, they get it back when the recalc is done.