# Make Vote after 30 Seconds

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, serial-voting, rate-limiting

Yesterday, I saw serial upvotes to my Questions and Answers.
Today all those upvotes were reversed, as per the rules.

But, today I see that I am being serial-downvoted. 
[image]

Now, I don't know if these serial downvotes get rollbacked or not tomorrow.

What I am thinking is, there should be a time difference between two votes, say 30 seconds.
So it can reduce serial voting.

Comment: So you want serial voters to silently get away with what they're doing by delaying their votes for them making sure they won't be reversed?

Comment: They'll be reversed, don't worry.

Comment: Or just allow people to vote as quickly as they would like so the system can catch people doing serial voting.

Comment: I want to be able to vote on several answers on a question, so -1 on the 'delays between votes' feature request. It certainly won't stop serial voting.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn : Yes

Comment: Serial up-voting? When does that happen when cheating isn't involved? And why hasn't it ever happened to me? :p

Comment: Why do you assume that these are not legitimate votes?

Comment: @CodyGray : On those post had I already got Upvotes.

Comment: So someone thinks they're worthy of an upvote, and someone else thinks they're worthy of a downvote. Not that weird. Getting an upvote doesn't mean you can never get a downvote.

Comment: I know I can get downvote and I am getting it.

Comment: @0x7fffffff It _does_ happen sometimes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140046/168333

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I disagree.

Firstly if I'm looking at a good question with 3 great answers I'll normally read everything then upvote what I believe should be within a few seconds; that's not serial upvoting but you're stopping me.

Secondly, it would be really annoying.

Lastly, I think this would *hurt* the capture of serial up/downvoting. Imagine that someone wants to serially downvote you. Instead of being able to get it out of the way in 3 minutes and make it easy for the reversal script to capture you're forcing them to spread it out, making it slightly harder to determine what's happening.

Comment: I'm hoping he's simply gravely misunderstood my first comment, because otherwise based on his response it sounds like that last bit is exactly what he wants.

Comment: I didn't notice your comment @Bolt but you've read the question in the same way I have. It looks as though the OP wants to make it harder to detect serial voting... *shrug*.

Comment: I don't think he knows *what* he wants.