# User systematically downvoting my contributions

Tags: support, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I’m the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)
>   [Punish serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98055/punish-serial-downvoting)

The ability to downvote questions anonymously without even the briefest of comments to give a rationale, is not good.  Every single question I've asked in the past few weeks, and every new one I ask now, [is being anonymously downvoted.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311343/tim?tab=reputation)

Can somebody help me rectify these undeserved downvotes?

Comment: Do you actually have a question or proposition for us, or is this just a rant?

Comment: What do you THINK the question might be, Mr Pieters?  Discussion is also a possibility. Not every post has to be a question.

Comment: To be fair, this downvoting pattern *does* look at bit suspicious... although requiring a rationale for voting is surely not the answer. *That* has been discussed about a million times, and rejected every time.

Comment: OK -- what is it called when some perfectly anonymous perpetrator instantly downvotes every new question one asks and goes back in time to find (unanswered) others that can be downvoted?

Comment: It's called serial downvoting and is usually reversed automatically by the system, but apparently this downvoter managed to stay under the radar of the [serial downvoting reversal script.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108029/serial-downvoting-is-it-detected-and-what-is-the-threshold) This might be worth bringing to moderator attention

Comment: Of course  it is rejected until it starts happening to YOU.

Comment: OK, give me a second to calm down.

Comment: @Tim That might be the wise decision. ;) You're probably rightfully upset, but we're not the enemy.

Comment: I take care to ask questions -- they're not dashed off by any means, and it frustrates me to no end to have them anonymously downvoted, sometimes within seconds of their being asked.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles That does not seem to be a dupe of this question, nor of the issue at hand.

Comment: I do see a "Serial downvoting reversed" in your rep history for 2 days ago. Looks like the script did its job there.

Comment: My suggestion: a question must be alive for at least 24 hours before the first anonymous downvote can be cast. "Signed" downvotes can occur at any time, as soon as it is posted.

Comment: @Martin Smith: but one hopes for TIMELY answers to one's question. If every new question I ask is killed in its crib, SO becomes a useless place for me, when it has been IMMENSELY useful to me in the past.

Comment: @Tim Do take a broad view though. You're (I'm assuming for now) the victim of a single user downvoting your contributions. No matter how annoying and discouraging this is to you, it's a single user. This is not an issue so rampant (to the best of my knowledge) that it needs such a severe solution as required comments for downvotes. (Which have a whole host of problems of their own, as discussed in earlier Meta questions).

Comment: Tim - I would just contact the team as @Rosinante suggests so they can investigate and take further action if someone seems to be singling you out personally.

Comment: @Bart: "severity" like beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Cute little sentence, but it fully ignores the various issues raised in the many previous discussions on the same or similar features.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently this isn't the first time it's happened to you (as mentioned, you've had a bout of downvotes reversed previously). I've hit whoever it is with a <s>stick</s> warning and hope he stops targeting you if that's what he really is doing... if you see your posts getting massively downvoted *again* after this, feel free to flag one of the affected posts to let us know and we'll investigate again.

For now, just remember that the downvotes will be reversed if they were really cast in quick bulk, as before.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the intervention. But I do hope my suggestion that a question should live for at least 24 hours before it can be anonymously killed merits some consideration.  Timeliness is an important concern.

Comment: There are approximately 100 prior examples of your suggestion; discussed at loving length, and ... rejected. You aren't adding anything new to this mixture.

Comment: Also, @Tim, suggestions made in comments can hardly be taken as a feature request?

Comment: @Rosinante:  Does the church minister get an accurate sense of his entire congregation if he polls only the choir?

Comment: Everyone in town has been polled on this subject. At length. Even the cows and the sheep.

Answer (score 6):

Your newest question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012095/kendo-ui-grid-feature-request-groupcollapse-event-that-exposes-the-array-of-di isn't a question. Feature requests don't have any place on SO.

Another of your downvoted questions, [Telerik Kendo UI grid: grouping and sorting survive grid.refresh() but collapsed groups get expanded; how to preserve state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13953278/) seems to be [an attempt to start a forum thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13991682), which isn't appropriate either.

I haven't looked too much further, but you should consider the possibility that *any number of persons* may be downvoting your questions because they're a *bad fit for the site*.

Comment: Indeed; despite the tag being sponsored, SE is not a replacement for Telerik's support site.

Comment: A good response, however: is Tim's vote of -6 on this meta question deserved or is this evidence he's being targeted?  The meta question doesn't seem like such a weird question to ask, even if it's a duplicate. (Disclaimer - my name is also Tim but I'm Tim from Sydney!)

Comment: @TimCooper There are several things at play here. Although it's a mere assumption, I guess several of the downvotes are for the original ranty-ness and the suggestion to require comments on downvotes (a suggestion which has been discussed to death here). Subsequent initial comments also didn't help. I don't see the Meta downvotes as any indication of targeting.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: my issue is not so much with downvoting per se as with anonymous, commentless downvoting, which leaves the questioner with no recourse but to GUESS about how to improve or rephrase the question. I don't care if it is one or a dozen anonymous downvoters. If the question is killed without so much as a comment, how do I know what is wrong with it and how to fix it?

Comment: @Tim: I don't know why you think of a single downvote as the question being "killed". Someone else can just as easily come along and upvote it.

Comment: @Arjan: Telerik invites users to use the public forums on SO, so I thought they might be shifting their support focus here. But I will not ask my Telerik-specific questions here going forward.

Comment: @Josh Caswell. I have no large statistical sample to draw upon, so it's only my anecdotal experience, but it seems a question with a -1 rating and no comments and no answers tends to wither on the vine. Maybe it needs to be improved or clarified so someone can take a crack at answering it, and that's why it languishes. Anonymous commentless downvoting is SELF-FULFILLING: it almost guarantees that that question will never be improved and become part of the signal rather than the noise.

Comment: @Tim: Telerik-specific but solvable technical problems are more than welcome. It's posts which can't meaningfully be answered by other SO users that are not

Comment: @Tim, if you know of any place where Telerik tells users to even post bug reports and feature requests on Stack Exchange, then please let team@stackoverflow.com know. I'm sure they'll ask Telerik to stop doing that then. (And if you see any place on the Telerik site where they call Stack Overflow *a forum*, then please let us know too... `;-)`)

Comment: @Arjan: I have no desire to get anyone in trouble except myself :-)  Perhaps Telerik is in the process of clarifying where, on SO, one should go for help.  I am sure that in at least one document I read, either on their site or in an email in response to my downloading a trial version, the potential customer was invited to so-called "public forums" on SO. It was I who understood that to mean "tagged as Kendo-ui" but today when I check their website, I see that they are directing users to a very specific location here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kendo-ui. Maybe my bad.

Answer (score 5):

Stalkers happen. Usually, the automatic protection system fixes it. When it doesn't, you contact the team, and they address it. You aren't the first person, and not the last. It happened to me once, in fact. I wasn't the rep that bothered me, it was that perfectly good answers were being made to look unhelpful, which wasn't helping the people I wrote them for.

Comment: I am working under a very tight deadline (Jan 1) to get a program into production using a UI library that is very new to me. The anonymous downvoter is threatening my livelihood not merely causing me some stress and inconvenience.  The problem is anonymous downvoting.

Comment: The problem is that you are depending on unpaid volunteers to get your paid job done. Over a holiday, no less.

Comment: @Tim That isn't really a sustainable approach to earning your livelihood. Ideally, you should be able to solve workplace problems regardless of whether SE evaporates tomorrow. That aside, you have my sympathy for the serial downvotes, it just sucks when that happens.

Comment: @Rosinante: That's B.S. I'm not "relying on unpaid volunteers". It is give-and-take here on S.O. I answer questions in the areas where I have most knowledge, and in return get answers to questions where I am most ignorant. That's the basic premise of this site. By the way, I lost thousands of points at one point when my identity was pinned to a particular email address. I'd been using different browsers at different locations as an unregistered contributor and many answer's I'd given somehow got lost. So the "picture" of how many answers I've given is not accurate.

Comment: @Asad: see my comment to Rosinante. Some days one answers questions. Some days one is the questioner. I rely upon this venue for help when I need it and offer others help when I can. I'm sure there have been times when the person I helped was not merely someone with a general curiosity but was trying to accomplish something at a job.  Are you suggesting that people who are getting paid to write programs should not be asking questions here, and that this site is for amateurs and people working as volunteers?